# Tensor contraction and notational problems

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

I am going through a chapter in my book on tensors, and it gives a basic understanding of tensors.

The question posed is simple: "Show that the contracted tensor $T_{ijk}V_k$ is a rank-2 tensor."

I followed the basic steps outlined earlier in the chapter, and cross checked with [Slader](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780471198260-mathematical-methods-in-the-physical-sciences/505/problems/4/#).

I understand the Slader answer uses the fact that the indicies can be arbitrary to do the math, but I am very new to tensors and am still trying to get the basics down. Before I looked up an answer, I got the following:

$$ \begin{align*}
 T^{'}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} &= a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} a_{\gamma k} T_{ijk}\\
 V^{'}_\gamma &= a_{\gamma k} V_k\\
 T^{'}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} V^{'}_\gamma &= a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} a_{\gamma k} T_{ijk}a_{\gamma k} V_k\\
 &= a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} a_{\gamma k} a_{\gamma k} T_{ijk} V_k\\
 &= a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} \delta_{\gamma k} T_{ijk} V_k\\
\end{align*} $$

Can someone offer some insight as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

Summing over the repeated index $k$ and using the properties of the delta function ...
$$a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} \delta_{\gamma k} T_{ijk} V_k = a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} T_{ij\gamma} V_\gamma$$
which is the transformation rule for a second rank tensor

Comment: Upon further reflection, would it not be the case that $a_{\gamma k} ^2 =1$

Comment: it would be much better not to have used the index $k$ twice, using $p$ instead ..
$$V^{'}_\gamma = a_{\gamma p} V_p$$
so then you can use
$$a_{\gamma k}a_{\gamma p}=\delta_{kp}$$

and we end up with ...
$$T^{'}_{\alpha\beta\gamma} V^{'}_\gamma = a_{\alpha i} a_{\beta j} T_{ijp} V_p$$

Comment: I understand that but am trying to understand this problem without using an arbitrary index. 

Unless I am completely misunderstanding the properties of the direction cosines and the $a$ term, since $a_{\gamma k} = a_{\gamma k}$ for all $\gamma$ and $k$, then $a_{\gamma k}a_{\gamma k}$ should just equal 1.

So far as I can tell $a_{\alpha k} a_{\beta k}=\delta_{\alpha \beta}$, but if $\alpha=\beta$ always (e.g. $\gamma$), then the result is just 1. In other words, the Kronecker delta functions step is actually unnecessary in this problem, though in general needed.